# Bring focus to inline tag editor

Tags: script, tags, editing

### Description

Focus the inline tag edit tool<sup>1</sup> when opened. Allows for using keyboard immediately to interact with the tags.

Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel the editing or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Part of [the moderator tools privilege](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) usually at 10k rep</sub>

### Installation

[Direct install (GitHub)](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-focus-inline-tag-editor/raw/main/src/focus-inline-tag-editor.user.js)

[See the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-focus-inline-tag-editor/blob/main/src/focus-inline-tag-editor.user.js)

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Focus inline tag editor
// @description     Focus inline tag editor when opened
// @author          VLAZ
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://superuser.com/*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/*
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @run-at          document-end
// @version         1.0.0
// ==/UserScript==
(() => {
    const taglistSelector = "#question .post-taglist";
    const tagsContainer = document.querySelector(taglistSelector);
    if (!tagsContainer)
        return;

    const inlineTagEditorSelector = "#edit-tags-form input#tageditor-replacing-tagnames--input";



    /* focus when opening tag editor */

    const findAndFocusInlineTagEditor = mutationList => {
        for (const mutation of mutationList) {
            if (mutation.type !== "childList")
                continue;

            if (mutation.addedNodes.length === 0)
                continue;

            const inlineTagEditor = mutation.target.querySelector(inlineTagEditorSelector);
            inlineTagEditor?.focus();
        }
    };

    const inlineEditObserver = new MutationObserver(findAndFocusInlineTagEditor);

    inlineEditObserver.observe(tagsContainer, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });



    /* cancel with Escape */

    const escapeToCancel = function(event) {
        if(event.target.matches(inlineTagEditorSelector)){
            if (event.isComposing)
                return; //discard
            if (event.code !== "Escape")
                return; //discard

            const cancelButton = event.currentTarget.querySelector("#edit-tags-cancel")
            if (!cancelButton) {
                console.warn(`Cancel button not found in parent element`, event.currentTarget);
                return;
            }
            cancelButton.click();
        }
    };
    
    tagsContainer.addEventListener("keyup", escapeToCancel);
})();
```

Comment: Related bug report on MSE: [Tabbing through the inline tag editor doesn't focus the input or allow adding new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389063/335251)